# How to unit test Bluetooth accessories?

Tags: android, ios, unit-testing, testing, bluetooth

I have an application with an Android and an iOS version, both of which function primarily by connecting and sending/receiving messages to/from Bluetooth accessories.

- iOS uses `ExternalAccessory` to connect to Bluetooth devices
- Android uses `BluetoothDevice` to connect to Bluetooth devices

I want to write unit tests to make them reliable.

Note that I am not looking to test what it sends/receives to the bluetooth device based on input/output (I already have that tested with stream wrappers). I need to test behavior like:

- The bluetooth accessory has disconnected in the middle of an operation
- A connection has failed

How to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

You can get a test framework like OCMock and create fake objects that represent what you would see in those scenarios.

[OCMock project page](http://ocmock.org/).